# Call to ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000); Hangs and does not return anything

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

It hangs and nothing is displayed on console.

Kafka Consumer Program.

```
package KafkaConsumer.Consumer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

public class ConsumerLoop implements Runnable {
  private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
  private final List<String> topics;
  private final int id;
  public ConsumerLoop(int id,
                      String groupId, 
                      List<String> topics) {
    this.id = id;
    this.topics = topics;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.61.245.54:9092");
    props.put("group.id", groupId);
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "60000");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
    props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);

      while (true) {
        System.out.println("Inside Loop");  
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(10);
        System.out.println("Lengthe of record  "+ records.count());
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
          Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
          data.put("partition", record.partition());
          data.put("offset", record.offset());
          data.put("value", record.value());
          System.out.println(this.id + ": " + data);
        }
      }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
      // ignore for shutdown 
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    consumer.wakeup();
  }
}
```

### Driver Program for Same

```
 package KafkaConsumer.Consumer;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
 import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 public class TestConumer {
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
      int numConsumers = 3;
      String groupId = "consumer-group";
      List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("consumer");
      final ExecutorService executor =    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numConsumers);

      final List<ConsumerLoop> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < numConsumers; i++) {
        ConsumerLoop consumer = new ConsumerLoop(i, groupId, topics);
        consumers.add(consumer);
        executor.submit(consumer);
      }

      Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          for (ConsumerLoop consumer : consumers) {
            consumer.shutdown();
          } 
          executor.shutdown();
          try {
            executor.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

}

Pom.xml for the Same

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>KafkaConsumer</groupId>
 <artifactId>Consumer</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>Consumer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
   <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
 <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
 <version>0.10.1.1</version>
 </dependency>  
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>0.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried it with both 2.0.10 and 2.0.9.

When I make the Executable Jar for the same and running it on the system through java -jar jarname it is running fine.

Connection is established for all 3 threads to the remote machine.
But Connection to Kafka Topic is not being established.

Hence conumer.poll(1000) hangs .

Please Suggest Solution.

Comment: Have you created the topic 'consumer' with at-least 3 partitions ? Does the topic 'consumer' contains any data ?

Comment: Yes I have created the topic and ran the producer for the same using these command. # bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic consumer --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --zookeeper localhost:2181

# bin/kafka-verifiable-producer.sh --topic consumer --max-messages 200000 --broker-list localhost:9092 . Is there a way to find topic contains data ?